# Using a 2fa authenticator with detox e2e tests

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm working on an app with 2fa confirmation for certain features. I want to test the features requiring 2fa confirmation on the app against the test backend. I didn't find any ways to do that yet, only unanswered questions about it. Has anyone managed to do it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it with [node-2fa](https://github.com/jeremyscalpello/node-2fa). First install the dependency

```
npm install node-2fa --save-dev
yarn add node-2fa --dev
```

Import the library to detox test file

```
const twofactor = require('node-2fa');
```

Call generateToken function where the 2fa token is needed

```
const newToken = twofactor.generateToken(‘YOUR_SECRET’);
await element(by.id('2fa-input')).typeText(newToken.token)
```